# how to remove class using jquery from two different document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two files index.html and index2.html

when i perform some function in index.html file that should effect index2.html file 

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('p button').click(function(){
              $('#ajax-messagebox').removeClass('ajax-modal');
          });
       });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p><button >Click ME</button></p>
    <div class="xyz">This is div 1</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**index2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ajax-messagebox" class="ajax-modal abc">This is div2 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is when i click on the "click me" button in index.html page i want "ajax-modal" class to be removed in index2.html

Comment: Many many options (both client and server side). One, for example, is to store a flag in the local/session storage

Comment: Are both's files loaded on the users screen?

Comment: In click you can call a function in some script as remove the class and are loaded in index2.html too.

Comment: ya both are loaded on the screen

Comment: @Vikky : Are both pages opened same time on the browser ?

Comment: @Vikky Are you saying both pages are open at once, and you want one to change dynamically when the other is changed? In that case you won't be using flags/cookies, as this rely on page being reloaded, but will want to either do AJAX polling or, the best way, use some sort of Pub/Sub to push changes to the page - you can use a hosted service like Pusher. But this depends on using a backend system - not just Javascript in the browser. Depending if you have user sessions, etc, this is a complicated question you may need to break into multiple stages.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this scenario by using `cookie`.

Try this

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script> //Cookie library
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('p button').click(function(){
            $.cookie("index_button_trigger", "yes"); // Set cookie                  
          });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button >Click ME</button></p>
<div class="xyz">This is div 1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script> //Cookie library
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
    setInterval(function() {
        if ($("#ajax-messagebox").hasClass("ajax-modal")) {
            if($.cookie("index_button_trigger")){
                $('#ajax-messagebox').removeClass('ajax-modal');
            }
        }           
    }, 1000); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ajax-messagebox" class="ajax-modal abc">This is div2 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the way u provided , i can get the class and i can read the data but im not able to remove it or rename it in any way, can u suggest any other way

Comment: @Vikky Can you explain your problem a little more brief ?